# How to connect Swagger 3 to an existing JWT Authentication service?

Tags: c#, api, .net-core, swagger, microservices

So the problem I want the approach is being able to connect my API Service to an already done JWT auth service. We send data to this endpoint **/client** ClientID and ClientSecret parameters, that will return us a Token Value with the payload data which later on we need to validate that Token Value so we send it to **/Validate** endpoint in order to get the final token which will have some claims on it.

So the question will be how can I connect my Swagger API to that.

All the services/API's are developed on .NET Core 3.1.

Swagger is using OAS 3

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code as well to configure your swagger

```
public static IServiceCollection ConfigureApiSwagger(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                var securityScheme = new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    Name = "Authorization",
                    Description = "JWT Bearer authorization",
                    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                    Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
                    Scheme = "bearer",
                    BearerFormat = "Bearer {token}",
                    Reference = new OpenApiReference
                    {
                        Id = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                        Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme
                    }
                };

                c.AddSecurityDefinition(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, securityScheme);
                c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
                {
                    { securityScheme, Array.Empty<string>() }
                });

                // Set the comments path for the Swagger JSON and UI.
                var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
                var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
                c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
            });
            return services;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
 public static void AddSwagger(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
            {

               var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
                var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
                options.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);

                options.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new ApiKeyScheme()
                {
                    Description = "API Key Authentication",
                    In = "header",
                    Name = "Authorization"
                });

                options.AddSecurityRequirement(new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>
                {
                    {"Bearer", Array.Empty<string>()}
                });

            });
        }
```